# Отказывается надуваться

Tags: android, xml

Прошу помощи
ловлю

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.corexis.jobhound, PID: 14513
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.corexis.jobhound/com.corexis.jobhound.view.homepage.MainPage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3121)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7076)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:829)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:902)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:554)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:383)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.corexis.jobhound.view.homepage.MainPage.onCreate(MainPage.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3101)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3264)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7076)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:363)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:456)
    at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:580)
    at me.ibrahimsn.lib.BottomBarParser.getTabConfig(BottomBarParser.kt:31)
    at me.ibrahimsn.lib.BottomBarParser.parse(BottomBarParser.kt:19)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar.<init> 
(SmoothBottomBar.kt:83)
        ... 28 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14513 SIG: 9
Process 14513 terminated.
```

Код activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.corexis.jobhound.R;

    public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation" />



<me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_nenu"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Добавили в зависимости "me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar"? https://jitpack.io/#ibrahimsn98/SmoothBottomBar/1.5

Comment: Да, все добавил

Comment: Закрывающий тег ConstraintLayout где? В конце его нет.

Comment: Можно посмотреть файл strings и bottom_nav_menu?

Comment: menu https://pastebin.com/Yqcf9aSe   strings https://pastebin.com/Qfj825y3 закрывающий тэг констрейна есть, просто обрезало при вставке сюда